# Eureka Service fails with exception after client connects

Tags: java, netflix, service-discovery, netflix-eureka

I am following the example from [here](https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/tree/master/eureka-examples).

I also have the Eureka server running on localhost:8080.

As a next step I attempt to run the sample service, like this:

```
./gradlew :eureka-examples:runExampleService
```

Here is the output that I get:

```
$ ./gradlew :eureka-examples:runExampleService --stacktrace
Inferred project: eureka, version: 1.4.6-SNAPSHOT
Publication mavenNebula not found in project :.
[buildinfo] Properties file path was not found! (Relevant only for builds running on a CI Server)
Publication named 'mavenNebula' does not exist for project ':' in task ':artifactoryPublish'.
None of the specified publications matched for project ':' - nothing to publish.
:eureka-client:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:eureka-client:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:eureka-client:classes UP-TO-DATE
:eureka-client:writeManifestProperties UP-TO-DATE
:eureka-client:jar
:eureka-examples:compileJava
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.7
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
1 warning
:eureka-examples:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:eureka-examples:classes
:eureka-examples:runExampleService
[main] WARN com.netflix.config.sources.URLConfigurationSource - No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
[main] INFO com.netflix.config.sources.URLConfigurationSource - To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sources, define System property archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls or make config.properties available on classpath.
[main] INFO com.netflix.config.DynamicPropertyFactory - DynamicPropertyFactory is initialized with configuration sources: com.netflix.config.ConcurrentCompositeConfiguration@46ee7fe8
[main] INFO com.netflix.config.util.ConfigurationUtils - Loaded properties file file:/Users/lenok/Documents/Programming/Github/eureka/eureka-examples/conf/sample-eureka-service.properties
[main] WARN com.netflix.config.util.ConfigurationUtils - file:/Users/lenok/Documents/Programming/Github/eureka/eureka-examples/conf/sample-eureka-service.properties is already loaded
[main] INFO com.netflix.appinfo.providers.EurekaConfigBasedInstanceInfoProvider - Setting initial instance status as: STARTING
[main] INFO com.netflix.discovery.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider - Using JSON encoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
[main] INFO com.netflix.discovery.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider - Using JSON decoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
[main] INFO com.netflix.discovery.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider - Using XML encoding codec XStreamXml
[main] INFO com.netflix.discovery.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider - Using XML decoding codec XStreamXml
[main] INFO com.netflix.discovery.shared.resolver.aws.ConfigClusterResolver - Resolving eureka endpoints via configuration
[main] INFO com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient - Disable delta property : false
[main] INFO com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient - Single vip registry refresh property : null
[main] INFO com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient - Force full registry fetch : false
[main] INFO com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient - Application is null : false
[main] INFO com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient - Registered Applications size is zero : true
[main] INFO com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient - Application version is -1: true
[main] INFO com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient - Getting all instance registry info from the eureka server
[main] INFO com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient - The response status is 200
[main] INFO com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient - Starting heartbeat executor: renew interval is: 30
[main] INFO com.netflix.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator - InstanceInfoReplicator onDemand update allowed rate per min is 4
Registering service to eureka with STARTING status
Simulating service initialization by sleeping for 2 seconds...
Done sleeping, now changing status to UP
[main] INFO com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient - Saw local status change event StatusChangeEvent [timestamp=1458260744041, current=UP, previous=STARTING]
Waiting ... verifying service registration with eureka ...
[DiscoveryClient-InstanceInfoReplicator-0] INFO com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient - DiscoveryClient_SAMPLEREGISTERINGSERVICE/Alenas-MacBook-Pro.local: registering service...
[DiscoveryClient-InstanceInfoReplicator-0] INFO com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient - DiscoveryClient_SAMPLEREGISTERINGSERVICE/Alenas-MacBook-Pro.local - registration status: 204
Waiting ... verifying service registration with eureka ...
Waiting ... verifying service registration with eureka ...
Service started and ready to process requests..
> Building 88% > :eureka-examples:runExampleService
```

After I start the client, like this:

```
$ ./gradlew :eureka-examples:runExampleClient
Inferred project: eureka, version: 1.4.6-SNAPSHOT
Publication mavenNebula not found in project :.
[buildinfo] Properties file path was not found! (Relevant only for builds running on a CI Server)
Publication named 'mavenNebula' does not exist for project ':' in task ':artifactoryPublish'.
None of the specified publications matched for project ':' - nothing to publish.
:eureka-client:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:eureka-client:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:eureka-client:classes UP-TO-DATE
:eureka-client:writeManifestProperties UP-TO-DATE
:eureka-client:jar
:eureka-examples:compileJava
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.7
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
1 warning
:eureka-examples:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:eureka-examples:classes
:eureka-examples:runExampleClient
[main] WARN com.netflix.config.sources.URLConfigurationSource - No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
[main] INFO com.netflix.config.sources.URLConfigurationSource - To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sources, define System property archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls or make config.properties available on classpath.
[main] INFO com.netflix.config.DynamicPropertyFactory - DynamicPropertyFactory is initialized with configuration sources: com.netflix.config.ConcurrentCompositeConfiguration@46ee7fe8
[main] INFO com.netflix.config.util.ConfigurationUtils - Loaded properties file file:/Users/lenok/Documents/Programming/Github/eureka/eureka-examples/conf/sample-eureka-client.properties
[main] WARN com.netflix.config.util.ConfigurationUtils - file:/Users/lenok/Documents/Programming/Github/eureka/eureka-examples/conf/sample-eureka-client.properties is already loaded
[main] INFO com.netflix.appinfo.providers.EurekaConfigBasedInstanceInfoProvider - Setting initial instance status as: STARTING
[main] INFO com.netflix.discovery.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider - Using JSON encoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
[main] INFO com.netflix.discovery.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider - Using JSON decoding codec JacksonJson
[main] INFO com.netflix.discovery.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider - Using XML encoding codec XStreamXml
[main] INFO com.netflix.discovery.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider - Using XML decoding codec XStreamXml
[main] INFO com.netflix.discovery.shared.resolver.aws.ConfigClusterResolver - Resolving eureka endpoints via configuration
[main] INFO com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient - Disable delta property : false
[main] INFO com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient - Single vip registry refresh property : null
[main] INFO com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient - Force full registry fetch : false
[main] INFO com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient - Application is null : false
[main] INFO com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient - Registered Applications size is zero : true
[main] INFO com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient - Application version is -1: true
[main] INFO com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient - Getting all instance registry info from the eureka server
[main] INFO com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient - The response status is 200
[main] INFO com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient - Not registering with Eureka server per configuration
Found an instance of example service to talk to from eureka: sampleservice.mydomain.net:8001
healthCheckUrl: http://Alenas-MacBook-Pro.local:8001/healthcheck
override: UNKNOWN
Connected to server. Sending a sample request: FOO Thu Mar 17 17:11:33 PDT 2016
Waiting for server response..
Received response from server: BAR Thu Mar 17 17:11:33 PDT 2016
Exiting the client. Demo over..

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 9.497 secs
```

It basically connects to the server and waits for response, etc.

At the same time on the service terminal I see the following happening. Sometimes when I do these actions I see the successful response on the eureka service:

```
Client got connected... processing request from the client
Received a request from the example client: FOO Thu Mar 17 17:30:16 PDT 2016
Sending the response to the client: BAR Thu Mar 17 17:30:16 PDT 2016
Simulating service doing work by sleeping for 10 seconds...
Removing registration from eureka
[main] INFO com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient - DiscoveryClient_SAMPLEREGISTERINGSERVICE/Alenas-MacBook-Pro.local - deregister  status: 200
Shutting down server. Demo over.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 4 mins 53.331 secs
```

And sometimes it gives errors, like here:

```
Client got connected... processing request from the client
Received a request from the example client: FOO Thu Mar 17 17:33:30 PDT 2016
Sending the response to the client: BAR Thu Mar 17 17:33:30 PDT 2016
Simulating service doing work by sleeping for 10 seconds...
Removing registration from eureka
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/netflix/discovery/shared/transport/decorator/EurekaHttpClientDecorator$2
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.cancel(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:71)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.unregister(DiscoveryClient.java:886)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.shutdown(DiscoveryClient.java:869)
    at com.netflix.eureka.ExampleServiceBase.stop(ExampleServiceBase.java:89)
    at com.netflix.eureka.ExampleServiceBase.start(ExampleServiceBase.java:80)
    at com.netflix.eureka.ExampleEurekaService.main(ExampleEurekaService.java:45)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$2
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 6 more
:eureka-examples:runExampleService FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':eureka-examples:runExampleService'.
> Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_73.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':eureka-examples:runExampleService'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:305)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:68)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:127)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:56)
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_73.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:365)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultJavaExecAction.execute(DefaultJavaExecAction.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.exec(JavaExec.java:60)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:218)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:211)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:200)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:579)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:562)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
    ... 47 more


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1 mins 1.267 secs
```

Please, help me get the example properly running. What might be the problem?